# Knockout.js - How to modify an observable JS Date object?

Tags: javascript, date, knockout.js

I have a ko.observable handling a JS Date object like so:

```
vm.date = ko.observable(new Date());
```

I need a simple function that can increase or decrease the date by x days. Like so:

```
vm.changeDay = function(x) {
  // I want this function to increase or decrease date by x days each time it is called.
};
```

The problem with my current implementations have been that the vm.date observable would not update in my View. This is probably because a JS Date object is more than a simple string, and need to be broken apart and put together in a specific way in order to be observable.
I tried using ko.computed to do this, but did not succeed.

See jsfiddle for a simple overview of the problem:
http://jsfiddle.net/tp6jb4x1/

Comment: Not sure you can do this: data-bind="click: changeDay(-1)", updated your fiddle to work: http://jsfiddle.net/tp6jb4x1/1/

Comment: data-bind="click: function(){ changeDay(-1); }"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The date logic was a little un-obvious so I updated your fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/tp6jb4x1/3

Relevant part:

```
... data-bind="click: changeDay.bind($data, 1)" ...

self.changeDay = function(dayDelta) {
    var d = this.date();
    d.setDate(d.getDate() + dayDelta);
    this.date(new Date(d.getTime()));
};
```

Your approach with a computable might have been working but the date logic might have been wrong.  I like using writeable computed observables instead of more complicated function calls wherever I can.

Comment: NOTE: I highly recommend just caving and using moment js for date logic.  Very nice library.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass your parameters in KO like this:

```
<button data-bind="click: changeDay.bind($data,'-1')">Prev day</button>
<button data-bind="click: changeDay.bind($data,'1')">Next day</button>
```

see ref: [Passing parameter using onclick or a click binding with KnockoutJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10039297/passing-parameter-using-a-click-binding-knockout-js)