# Change value of observable to 1 and 0 onclick knockout js

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a observable

```
self.oneOrZero = ko.observable(0);
```

I want to change the value of this observable to 1 or 0 by clicking just one button.

```
<button data-bind="onclick : " > Change </button>
```

Comment: Knockout has a built-in handler called click. Then try something like `self.toggle = function () { self.oneOrZero(self.oneOrZero() ? 0 : 1) }` Ex: `data-bind="click: toggle"`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing parameter using onclick or a click binding with KnockoutJS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10039297/passing-parameter-using-onclick-or-a-click-binding-with-knockoutjs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the mod operator to switch from 0 to 1 and vice versa. **use click binding, as onclick is not recognized on knockout**

```
self.oneOrZero = ko.observable(0);
self.toggle = function() {
  self.oneOrZero((self.oneOrZero() + 1) % 2);
}

<button data-bind="click : toggle" > Change </button>
```

Comment: Good answer, but is it not a bit overkill to use the `%` operator? Why not just `self.oneOrZero(self.oneOrZero() ? 0 : 1);` (as Neps also commented before me)

Comment: Hmmm yes, perhaps. In terms of cost I don't know which one is more efficient: type conversion or mod operator. In terms of code, for me is more natural to use mod, as we are dealing with numbers, not booleans... but I think is more a preference issue. Perhaps Boolean(self.oneOrZero()) ? 0 : 1, or self.oneOrZero() === 1 ? 0 : 1. Javacript is really flexible on conversions, but I always prefer to avoid this.